# a4j:commandButton's action is never triggered when it's inside a rich:panel with rendered tag

Tags: jsf, richfaces, ajax4jsf

Here is the simplified version of my xhtml code, I can't figure out why my *save1* commandButton doesn't work while *save2* works:

```
   <rich:panel id="table_panel">
    <h:form>
    <rich:panel rendered="#{bean.showPanel}">
        <a4j:commandButton id="save1" value="Save" 
            action="#{bean.executeAction()}">
       </rich:panel>
       <rich:panel>
        <a4j:commandButton id="save2" value="Save2" 
            action="#{bean.executeAction()}">
       </rich:panel>
      </h:form>
    </rich:panel>
```

When click a button, it will update *showPanel* value to *true* in backend and re-render *table_panel*,
then commandButton *save1* will show up, but even if it show up, the action *executeAction()*
will never be invoked after click (never enter into my breakpoint in the method). However, the commandbutton *save2* can always act normally.

The only difference for those two buttons is their wrapper rich:panel, one is always there while 
another is displayed after some UI action as it has **rendered="#{bean.showPanel}"** attribute. I didn't see any javascript errors on firebug.

I would appreciate any ideas, thanks in advance!

Comment: Thanks for the useful link, that fifth possibility looks close to my issue. However, I haven't figured out a way to get around.

Comment: What scope is bean in? If bean is request scoped, the `#{bean.showPanel}` is reinitialized to default when the bean is newly recreated during processing the form submit. This construct requires at least a view scoped bean, or you must maintain the state in bean's (post)constructor based on request parameters. The answer at point 5 is pretty explicit in this. I'm not sure what part you didn't understood and why you still didn't tell anything about the bean's scope after reading that.

Comment: Looks like the issue goes away when I extend the scope of bean from Page to Session (I'm using Seam framework), I just realized it didn't work because I accidentally made another mistake. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try putting execute="@this" explicitly in the commandButton.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `immediate="true"`, it might narrow down the issue in my opinion:

```
<a4j:commandButton id="save1" value="Save" immediate="true"
    action="#{bean.executeAction()}">
```